# How to ensure that an app is correctly signed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I currently run a small company which makes iPhone Apps. - I've been using my team development resources to build apps to device on Xcode (i.e. I'm creating the app as a member of the company).

I've just finished making my own app which I want to submit to the app store (**not** as a part of the company). - I'm just about to get my own individual license - when I have it, what steps should I take to ensure that the App is signed/provisioned with my individual license??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the codesign -dvvv command from the terminal command-line on your app bundle to verify and print out the certificate used for signing.  Make sure that it is your Distribution certificate, not Development or someone else's certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what's your provisioning profile and sign the app with it, but if you haven't create the app in the [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) you won't be able to upload it anyway, so it doesn't matter.

Let me explain: before you actually upload the application to be reviewed by the Apple guys, you need to login in your [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) account and create the app (name, description, bundle id, etc). Only then, on the Xcode, you will be able to upload it.